# GCP VM Instance compromised. How to secure it?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

So last night I got a mail from google-cloud-compliance that one of the VM instances have some critical problems and it will be suspended after 72 hours if the pattern is continued and appeal not filed. Below is the mail I received.

> We have  recently detected that your Google Cloud Project has been
>   performing intrusion attempts against a third-party and appears to be
>   violating our Terms of Service. Specifically, we detected port
>   scanning on remote port 22 originating from your Compute Engine
>   project targeting more than 4451 IP addresses between 2019-04-02 09:31
>   and 2019-04-02 09:55 (Pacific Time). Please check the traffic
>   originating from all your instances and fix any other instances that
>   may be impacted by this.

To access the VM via ssh you've to add your public key in the instance itself and A minimal Django project is deployed in the instance so I don't think it was due to both of these things. So my question is what caused it and how I can secure my VM instance.

Comment: How do you access your instance? Is your root user opened? Is there password on the instance? Wich user is running your django? Are the fw rules configured correctly?

Comment: @night-gold to access the instance public key needs to be added to the instance in google console and by mentioning the private key instance is accessed. django is configured through the root user. I am not sure what you mean by forwarding rules.

Comment: I'm familiar with google authentification I was juste checking. The biggest issue here is the user wich make your django run... If the attacker is using a security breach of django he has full access to your compute instance... Never run something as root... I asked about the firewall rules to know if you did not leave some port opened that could be closed because unused by your app but could be used to attack.

Comment: @night-gold Ok I'll look into it thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I will strongly recommend you to delete your VM instance, as you cannot be completely sure about until what extent it has been compromised.

Once everything has been recreated again, you can take some measures to try to prevent this from happening again. As stated in the comments, I will use strong passwords and I will make sure that all the software you are using is properly updated and patched, especially Django.

Also, I would take a look to the firewall rules, using the least privilege best-practice. For example, you can make sure that only the IPs you are using to access your instance are allowed in port 22.

Finally, I would suggest you to take a look to [this](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-view-vulnerabilities-threats#etd). It is a new Beta feature that allows you to detect “DDoS attacks originating inside your organization”. Besides you can check [this best practices](https://securitytrails.com/blog/mitigating-ssh-based-attacks-top-15-best-security-practices) in order to harden SSH access. Especially remarkable among them is https://www.sshguard.net/ which is able to recognize patterns  such as several login failures within a few seconds and then block the offending IP.